# Android unable to build Linphone source code

Tags: android, linphone

i am working on Linphone for android for sipcall.

I downloaded the source code for Linphone from the following link

[link](https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-android)

when i am importing my source code in Eclipse (Windows7) , i am getting following error, says "jar is missing"

[image]

How i resolve this issue , please help me , i am new in this.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: simply, you need to add jar files into your project. If you have all jar files then copy to them and paste in `libs` folder of your project

Comment: Check out this: https://astutesols.wordpress.com/2015/12/02/building-linphone-for-android-on-mac-os/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use command

`git clone http://git.linphone.org/git/linphone-android.git --recursive`. If you just download `zip` submodules with all `*.jar` files will not be downloaded.

Comment: import org.linphone.core.LinphoneCoreListenerBase; missing classes

Comment: You need to build native code to generate this class. Or you may add `linhpone.jar` from linphone sdk which can be downloaded from official web [site][1]


  [1]: http://www.linphone.org/technical-corner/liblinphone/downloads

Comment: @vovaxo I trying to build native code, but getting cmake error. When compiling process-3. Error gccexecutable path not found in cmake. I am used ubuntu 16.04.